# div element and display inline-block

Tags: html, css

I've tried for a while to understand why this code doesn't works as expected.

The following code should display a white stripe, green stripe, white stripe, without gap.

There's three divs inside a container, all 2 div are 20% width, one is 60% width, border, padding, margin is 0.

The question is why do I still see a "margin", between white and green block?

if you wanna give a try

https://jsbin.com/lexekimoba/edit?html,css,output

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0px solid red;
}

body {
  background-color: #888;
}

.container1 {
  background-color: #aaa;
}

.main {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.side {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="side">s</div>
  <div class="main">
    abcdef
  </div>
  <div class="side">s</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code sets both left and right sides to white, regardless of how they  display. You need an extra class in order to get a red div or else you will end up with white|green|white. Your `solid red` is only a `border` `style` and `color` and as it has no line width (it's set to 0) it will never show
Remove the background color from the side and create two other classes ; l and r ( for left and right) Add the class after side (.l/.r) in html to get white on left and red to right .main {width: 58.5%; etc.. }.side {same ..remove bgcolor} .l{background-color:white;}    .r{background-color:red;}

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/mc71ocr6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to the linebreaks between the DIVs (in the HTML code). If you remove those, it works:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0px solid red;
}

body {
  background-color: #888;
}

.container1 {
  background-color: #aaa;
}

.main {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.side {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="side">s</div><div class="main">
    abcdef
  </div><div class="side">s</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

White space between two inline divs are considerable and visible.

Try removing all white spaces between inline divs.

For better explanation read this great article by css-tricks

[Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

> Here's the deal: a series of inline-block elements formatted like you
>   normally format HTML will have spaces in between them.

Also, you may want to read [Remove Whitespace Between Inline-Block Elements](https://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the white space between the divs

```css
*{ 
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0px solid red;  
}


body{
 background-color: #888;
 
}

.container1{ 
 background-color: #aaa;
 
}

.main{
 width: 60%;
 background-color: green;
 display: inline-block;
 box-sizing: border-box; 
 
}

.side{
    box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 20%;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: white;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>div align</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="divalign.css">
 </head>
 <body>

  <div class="container1">
          <div class="side">s</div><div class="main">
     abcdef 
   </div><div class="side">s</div>
          
  </div>


 </body>
</html>
```

or use `<!-- -->` between the inline block elements.

```css
*{ 
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0px solid red;  
}


body{
 background-color: #888;
 
}

.container1{ 
 background-color: #aaa;
 
}

.main{
 width: 60%;
 background-color: green;
 display: inline-block;
 box-sizing: border-box; 
 
}

.side{
    box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 20%;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: white;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>div align</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="divalign.css">
 </head>
 <body>

  <div class="container1">
          <div class="side">s</div><!--
   --><div class="main">
     abcdef    
   </div><!-- 
          
          --><div class="side">s</div><!--
          
  --></div>


 </body>
</html>
```

You can read more about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)